# What type of graphic will be suitable for 3 continuous vs 1 categorical variable

Tags: categorical-data, data-visualization, descriptive-statistics, continuous-data, ggplot2

I want to create a graphic to explore relationship between 3 continuous and 1 categorical variable.
 I have 2 different examples I want to investigate.

1-
the numeric variables are

- num of bedrooms range (1-10)
- num of bathrooms range (1-8)
- num of people accommodates (1-16)

categorical variable is

- availability (3 levels)

2-

- Blood Pressure (2-150)
- Blood Urea (1-400)
- Sodium (4-200)

categorical variable is

- chronic Kidney Disease (Yes and No)

what would be the ideal graphics to explore the relationship between all 4 variables in each example.

Comment: Simplest may be three scatterplots for bed vs bath, bed vs people, bath vs people, with points in each of two colors (or symbols) for available/unavailable. maybe see [this](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/scatter-plot-matrices-r-base-graphs).

Comment: I would do 3D scatter plots with surface fitting for each level, e.g., kidney disease yes/no.

Answer (score 1):

First, none of these variables is continuous. You can't have 1.320 bedrooms.

Second, you say "all three" but I think you mean "all four".

Third, what graphic you should use depends on exactly what you want to show. Some choices here are:

1. A scatterplot matrix
2. A mosaic plot
3. Some sort of lattice plot

Comment: It could also be blood sugar, blood urea, serum creatinine and binary variable Chronic Kidney Disease.

Comment: That would be completely different. Please post your ACTUAL problem.

Comment: I updated the question